# Converting String to Hex in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to convert strings to hexadecimals in my Excel VBA macro.

I tried:

```
Dim val As String
val = "10"
Dim hexVal As Integer
hexVal = Convert.ToInt32(val, 16)
```

but `Convert.ToInt32(val, 16)` does not work, I'm guessing because it's not VB.NET?

Anyway, I can use `CInt(val)` to convert a string to an integer but if I have the string representation of a hex value, e.g. "3366CC", how do I convert it to hex so that I can perform hex calculations on it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In VBA you need to mess about with the `&H` literal:

```
value = val("&H" & "10") '// 16
value = val("&H3366CC")  '// 3368652
```

**Edit**

```
Function FromHex(hexString As String) As Long
    FromHex = Val("&H" & hexString)
End Function
```

Then

```
resultString = hex$(FromHex("3366CC") / FromHex("A"))
```

Or for constants obviously;

```
resultString = hex$(FromHex("3366CC") / &HA)
```

Comment: How would I perform a hex calculation such as `3366CC / A` to get `523E1`?

Comment: Note that if your hex number is between 8000 and ffff, it will be treated as a 16 bit signed integer. For example: &hD001 is treated as -12287. To explicitly treat it as 32 bit signed integer, append the number with &, for example &hd001& -> 53249.

Answer (score 7):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim val As String, hval As String
    val = "10"
    hval = Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(val)
    MsgBox hval
End Sub
```

**VBA** code needs to know or make an assumption about the input string.  The code above assumes that the string represents a *decimal* value.

If the input string is *Hex,* then:

```
Sub dural2()
    Dim val As String, hval As Long
    val = "10"
    hval = Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(val)
    MsgBox hval
End Sub
```

Here *hval* can be used arithmetically.

Comment: Doesn't this only convert decimals to hexadecimals? What if I have string `val = "3366CC"` and I need to convert it to hex to perform a hex calculation such as `3366CC / A` to get `523E1`?

Comment: @taa  **VBA** needs to know the base of the input string..........is _100_ really 100 decimal or 256 decimal