# How to delete character in excel-vba?

Tags: string, excel, cells, vba

How could I delete a specific character (like 'u') that appears in a string in every cell of a column?

Comment: Wellcome to Stackoverflow.  Your question is a quite ambigous.  Can you post the content of that column in code format?

Comment: It's something like this:                                                                                                         4u                                                                                                                                   F0u                                                                                                                                0x20u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Public Sub replaceChar()

    'Looping from row 1 to 5000, you can modify 50000 to what you want.
    For row = 1 To 5000 Step 1

        'Replace character in all cell from first column
        Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(row, 3).Value = Replace(Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(row, 3).Value, "u", "")

    Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Error: "Subscript out of range". Any advice?

Comment: @Nicolas But, that snippet will replaces all occurrences of the character `u` that was in the column.  If the `u` that she want to delete is only the first `u`...

Comment: You need to put this blog between sub. Ok, I modified my code. Try with it.

Comment: No, he said to replace "u", not first "u".

Comment: I have a single column in my sheet that looks like this : Column C

0x40u
1u
2u
3u
4u

Comment: One more question. You think I could replace that 5000 to LastRow?

Comment: Yes, you should do it for avoid waste looping.

Comment: @Nicolas Sorry to bother you again.But can you help me with another thing? I have to put in a cell the hex value of another cell value. I tried Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 4).Value = Hex(Cells(i, 3))...and i need to specify that i have a for i=1 to lastrow

Comment: Try with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363113/converting-string-to-hex-in-excel-vba

Comment: @Nicolas I tried with Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(val) and doesn't work. And with Val("&H" & val) 10 will be 16 and so on, but I need 10 to be A