# Write hex-string to file in binary mode

Tags: excel, vba, binaryfiles

I want to write the hexadecimal values to a binary file in order they look the same when I open in hex editor.

My current code is this:

```
Sub Write2Binary()
Dim i As Integer
Dim nFileNum As Integer
Dim sFilename As String

sFilename = "D:\OutputPath\Test.bin"

strBytes = "F3 A1 02 00 04 00 8D 24 44 C3 8C 03 83 49 26 92 B5"
arrBytes = Split(strBytes)

nFileNum = FreeFile

Open sFilename For Binary Lock Read Write As #nFileNum

For i = LBound(arrBytes) To UBound(arrBytes)
    Put #nFileNum, , arrBytes(i)
Next i

Close #nFileNum

End Sub
```

This code produces the following binary file that when I open it in a Hex editor looks like this:

```
08 00 02 00 46 33 08 00 02 00 41 31 08 00 02 00 
30 32 08 00 02 00 30 30 08 00 02 00 30 34 08 00 
02 00 30 30 08 00 02 00 38 44 08 00 02 00 32 34 
08 00 02 00 34 34 08 00 02 00 43 33 08 00 02 00 
38 43 08 00 02 00 30 33 08 00 02 00 38 33 08 00 
02 00 34 39 08 00 02 00 32 36 08 00 02 00 39 32 
08 00 02 00 42 35
```

That is different to the content I want to have in binary file. When I open the file in Hex editor I like to see the following content:

```
F3 A1 02 00 04 00 8D 24 44 C3 8C 03 83 49 26 92 B5
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26363210/4088852)?

Comment: I'm not sure if that link answers my question

Comment: You're outputting 4 bytes of `String` for each value (2 per character). You just need to convert them to numbers from hex strings.  That link answers the question of how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data represents Hex values of bytes to be wriiten to a binary file.  `Split` produces an array of strings, each element being a string represention of a hex value.  As Comintern told you, you need to convert them to numbers.

`Put` uses the type of the `Varname` parameter to determine the length (number of bytes) to write, so in this case you need to convert to `Byte`, so use `CByte` to convert. `CByte` also needs to know the values are Hex, so prepend with `&H`

All up, your code becomes

```
Sub Write2Binary()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim nFileNum As Integer
    Dim sFilename As String
    Dim strBytes As String
    Dim arrBytes As Variant

    sFilename = "D:\OutputPath\Test.bin"

    strBytes = "F3 A1 02 00 04 00 8D 24 44 C3 8C 03 83 49 26 92 B5"
    arrBytes = Split(strBytes)

    nFileNum = FreeFile

    Open sFilename For Binary Lock Read Write As #nFileNum

    For i = LBound(arrBytes) To UBound(arrBytes)
        Put #nFileNum, , CByte("&H" & arrBytes(i))
    Next i

    Close #nFileNum
End Sub
```